# Embedding pods to static library iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, static-libraries

I'm creating a static library in iOS using Objective-C. This library will gather data from the app where this library is integrated, the gathered data from the app will be sent to the server. 
I'm just wondering if is it possible to embed a cocoa pods framework in my library like AFNetworking?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It seems to be possible.
I created a static library project and tried to integrate cocoapods in to it with below steps.

```
pod init
```

Then edited the podfile to integrate AFNetworking pod in the project like below

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Testing' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

  # Pods for Testing

end
```

then gave

```
pod install
```

I get the below warning

> [!] The Podfile contains framework or static library targets
>   (Testing), for which the Podfile does not contain host targets
>   (targets which embed the framework). If this project is for doing
>   framework development, you can ignore this message. Otherwise, add a
>   target to the Podfile that embeds these frameworks to make this
>   message go away (e.g. a test target).

As the first line in the warning says we are doing framework development, hence we can ignore this message and it should work fine.

Also my suggestion is to use Alamofire instead of AFNetworking as Alamofire is swift based and AFNetworking is objective-c based.